# Xcode 15 CocoaPods v1.13.0 "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code"

Tags: ios, cocoapods

```
Showing All Messages
rsync: mkstemp "/Users/jaygajjar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ContourHDK-cdjmrpbfxbvfwkcknsjwotshutcp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ContourHDK.app/Frameworks/CryptoSwift.framework/.CryptoSwift.QeMcJP" failed: Operation not permitted (1)

rsync: mkstemp "/Users/jaygajjar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ContourHDK-cdjmrpbfxbvfwkcknsjwotshutcp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ContourHDK.app/Frameworks/CryptoSwift.framework/.Info.plist.5y0PRL" failed: Operation not permitted (1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to check that ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING is disabled in the project's build settings.

Comment: Jay Gajjar this worked!  Thank you. Can you explain how that "operation not permitted" error was resolved by ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING set to NO?

Answer (score -1):

I resolved it by installing the Xcode 15 beta 5 version that the community was saying doesn't have this bug, after that I updated it to LTS version from the App store, this setup kept the library files that resolved the issue.